# Removing author name from all posts only if post author is admin (wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, function, blogs

I can't seem to find the function code that will work for this to actually completely remove the author from posts only if the author is an admin. I have generic posts which will be published by admin but I do not want to have the admins name appear as an author (need it to be completely removed) Is there a way to do this without hiding it but rather completely remove it?

Worse case I can hide the Div element but haven't been able to find the code to accomplish this when the author of the post is an admin only. I can also use the user ID if that works as well to remove the author.
Thanks!

Comment: Share your code

Comment: Ryan try below code I think you archive your functionality

Answer (score 0):

```
function get_user_role($post_authr_id) {
    $user = new WP_User($post_authr_id);
    return array_shift($user->roles);
}

global $post;
$post_authr_id = $post->post_author;
$auhtor_role = get_user_role($post_authr_id);

if($auhtor_role !== 'administrator'){

    //if auhor role is not admin display auhtor name

    /*

        your author display code here

    */
}
```